# Скрывать div в AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Есть код регистрации с помощью  AJAX . По условию должно выводить #div1 если логин и пароль не правильно введены ,а "#result1","#result2" скрывать и наоборот если все правильно введено то "#result1","#result2" показывается ,а #div1  скрывается . И по идее должно выводить через JSON echo "{'ID'='1','name'='Name'}";   1 и Name

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>титулка</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">  
function myEvent(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){ 
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){ 

var ID   = xmlhttp.responseText; // ID
var Name = xmlhttp.responseText; // Name

if (ID!="0") {
    document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML= ID;
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML= Name;

    ("#result1","#result2").hide(); // Скрывает div1.
   ("#div1").show(); // Показывает div2.
}

}
}

var val_x = document.getElementById("n111").value; 
var val_y = document.getElementById("n222").value; 


xmlhttp.open("GET","connect.php?n111="+val_x+"&n222="+val_y,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>                                                  
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1">
<p id="status"></p>
Ввести текст
<p>login <input id="n111" name="log"></p>
<p>passw <input id="n222" name="pas"></p>
<input type="button" value="Передать данные" onclick="myEvent()" />
<br><br><br>
</div>
<div id="result1">0</div>
<div id="result2">0</div>
</body>

</html>
```

connect.php

```
<?php

if($_GET['n111']=="tech_user"){
    if($_GET['n222']=="1234") {

    echo "{'ID'='1','name'='Name'}";

    }
}else{
    echo "{'ID'='0','name'='xxxx'}";
}


?>
```

Comment: В чем проблема-то?

Comment: div не скрывается и не открывается если пароль введен правильно , проблема с этим куском ,видимо еще где-то затрагивается .("#result1","#result2").hide(); // Скрывает div1.
   ("#div1").show(); // Показывает div2.

Comment: может синтаксис не правильный , не пойму .

Comment: попробуйте `document.getElementById("result1").style.display = "none";` и блок соответственно

Comment: у вас тут все не правильно, что у вас возвращает xmlhttp.responseText ?

Comment: @Walfter у него в var ID   = xmlhttp.responseText; точно не приходит ID с json'a

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex заюзайте уже какой-нибудь фреймворк, тот же jQ читать проще, работать тоже и вот такие грамосские конструкции `document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML= ID;` станут такие `$('#result1').html(ID);`

Comment: Решил опробовать JSON , друзья говорили что с ним проще работать но я вчера только начал его изучать )

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex прежде чем резко приступать к работе почитайте про структуру

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Оххх... Я если честно не знаю с чего начать. Первые чувства: как на собеседовании: *найдите что не так в этом коде и поправьте*. А косяков тут куча, начиная от двух `</head>`, `("#result1","#result2")`, инпуты без формы, `var ID   = xmlhttp.responseText;` и тоже самое с `NAME` (это вообще как по вашему должно работать?) и заканчивая вашими словами: `...если все правильно введено то "#result1","#result2" показывается ,а #div1 скрывается ...` - хотя по коду все иначе.

Даже в `connect.php` - косяки, `echo "{'ID'='1','name'='Name'}"` - это не `JSON` формат. Есть ситуации где connect ничего не вернет - такого не должно быть.

Давайте я просто оставлю в **Вашем стиле** рабочий пример:

**Первый файл:**

```
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>титулка</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            .hide-block {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function myEvent() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "connect.php?n111=" + $('#n111').val() + "&n222=" + $('#n222').val(),
                    success: function (data) {
                        var NEW_JSON = JSON.parse(data);
                        var ID = NEW_JSON.ID;
                        var Name = NEW_JSON.name;
                        if (ID != "0") {
                            $('#result1').html(ID);
                            $('#result2').html(Name);
                            $("#result1, #result2").show();
                            $("#div1").hide();
                        }else{
                            $("#status").show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">
        <p id="status" class="hide-block">Неправильно!</p>
        Ввести текст
        <p>login <input id="n111" name="log"></p>
        <p>passw <input id="n222" name="pas"></p>
        <input type="button" value="Передать данные" onclick="myEvent()" />
        <br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div id="result1" class="hide-block">0</div>
    <div id="result2" class="hide-block">0</div>
</body>

</html>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
if (($_GET['n111'] == "tech_user") AND ($_GET['n222'] == "1234")) {
    echo json_encode(array('ID' => '1', 'name' => 'Name'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('ID' => '0', 'name' => 'xxxx'));
}
```

Comment: Впервые вижу `jQuery.parseJSON(data);` Обычно делаю всегда `JSON.parse(data);` =)))

Comment: jQ возвращает массив? Но ведь у JS нет ассоциативных массивов это всё равно будет объект?

Comment: из документации >Если браузер обладает собственной функцией JSON.parse для обработки json-данных, то jQuery воспользуется ей при выполнении $.parseJSON()

Comment: @Walfter согласен c Вами, но отсюда все равно следует вывод что лучше использовать jquery

Comment: Не я всегда за пользование фреймворками=) И прикольно видеть в коде часть с jQ часть с DOM JS `document.getElementById("result1").innerHTML = ID;document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = Name;`

Comment: @Walfter мне влом все переписывать, кусками копировал, я указал что `В стиле автора` - я так и написал. переписывать с нуля... оно мне надо? :<

Comment: Я немного не понял этот кусок ,а точнее что записываеться в  переменной NEW_JSON   что это ($.parseJSON(data); )

Comment: @Walfter по просьбе трудящихся ;)

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex У вас в `data` ответ от `connect.php` В нашем случае там строка в `JSON`-формате (например: `{"ID":"0","name":"xxxx"}`). Так вот, `$.parseJSON(data)` - переводит эту строку в массив, и этот массив мы записываем в `NEW_JSON`, чтобы потом забить в переменные (следующие 2 строчки).

Comment: А выводить данные "ID":"0" или же "name":"xxxx" можно в отдельных div или нет чтоб не записывалось только в одну строку ?

Comment: А то оно все смешалось

Comment: типа значение с ID сначала ,а снизу чтоб выводилось name

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex У меня все так и делается. Просто вы сами написали что в случае успеха показывать ID и NAME. Я посчитал что успех это `ID` != 0. Посмотрите сами на код

Comment: @technoimpextechnoimpex `var ID = NEW_JSON.ID; var Name = NEW_JSON.name;` - тут мы записываем в ID - ответный ид, а в Name - ответный нейм. Дальше мы `в случае успеха`: `$('#result1').html(ID); $('#result2').html(Name); $("#result1, #result2").show();` Записываем их в дивы и показываем.

Comment: Все ,теперь понял )Спасибо вам огромное . Как к вам можно обратиться если будут вопросы (по возможности)?

Comment: сейчас найду Вас

Comment: если что я Андрей Павлов