# Как вернуть данные скрипта после выполнения php-скрипта?

Tags: php, ajax, post

Есть ajax-запрос. Мне надо передать в php-скрипт данные путем этого запроса и получить из php-скрипта другие данные. Как это можно реализовать?

```
'$('#docx').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?=$dir?>/ajax/ajax_editor_docx.php',
        data: {text: $('#area').val() },
        success: function(){
                ConvertToDocx();
                window.location.href = "<?=$_SERVER["SCRIPT_URI"]?>";
            },
        })
    });'
```

Функция ConvertToDocx()

```
function ConvertToDocx(){
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.setAttribute('href', 'path');
        link.setAttribute('download', '<?=rand(1,10000).'.docx';?>');
        onload = link.click();
    }
```

Сам php-обработчик

```
PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setOutputEscapingEnabled(true);
            $parsedownM = new Parsedown();
            $htmlReadyM = $parsedownM->text($_REQUEST["text"]);
            $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
            $section = $phpWord -> addSection();
            \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Shared\Html::addHtml($section, $htmlReadyM);
                $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
                $cacheDir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/upload/pdfFiles/';
                $name = rand(1,1000).'.docx';
                $objWriter->save($cacheDir.$name);
```

Comment: Ну раз есть `ajax` то уже все сделано в чем проблема? Я сегодня уже приводил пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849978/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-div-%D0%B2-ajax/849995#849995 Там есть и прием и отдача.

Comment: Если у вас уже есть ajax-запрос, то это хорошее начало. Приведите его, и расскажите, в чем дальше сложность заключается?

Comment: **upd**
@teran код в описании

Comment: @teran задача заключается в конвертации текста в docx документ

Comment: @Manitikyl, проблема в том, что я не понимаю как передать ссылку обратно из скрипта